# Check string contains a list element using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I know that `listcontains()` is used to check the list contains a specified string. And is there any way to check a string contains a list element using Coldfusion?

Comment: what do you want to check, specific element of a list in a sting or complete list in your string?
cause list itself is a string and the elements are separated by a delimiter

Comment: @Keshavjha I need specific element of a list in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(yourList)#" index="elemementNumber">
<cfif yourString contains ListGetAt(elemementNumber)>
yes
<cfelse>
no
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is ListFindNoCase() or ListFind() depending on the obvious.

Comment: No I need to check, the string contains a specific element of the list.

Comment: @RajeshManilal - This is the type of question that would benefit from an simple example.